# Why does the clinfo show that no devices found in platform?

Tags: release-loki

It doesn't happen in Ubuntu, but happens in elementary OS Loki.
[image]

No devices found in platform.

iGPU: intel HD4600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed beignet, and it was solved.